# Spring Cloud SQS listener receives empty POJO

Tags: java, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I use Spring Cloud: **spring-cloud-aws-messaging** to implement SNS + SQS.
I have SQS listener:

```
 @Transactional
  @SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
  public void processMessage(UserEvent userEvent) {
    try {
      System.out.println(userEvent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e);
    }
  }
```

with configuration

```
 @Bean
  public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync);
  }

  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory(
      final ObjectMapper mapper, final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync){

    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueHandlerFactory =
        new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    queueHandlerFactory.setArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(
        new PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(jackson2MessageConverter(mapper))
    ));
    return queueHandlerFactory;
  }

  private MessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter(final ObjectMapper mapper){
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return converter;
  }
```

UserEvent is a POJO with setters/getters and default constructor.
The issue is that SQS listener receives empty object.
I suspect that **QueueMessageHandlerFactory** has wrong configuration.
If I change SQS listener argument to String I receive message:

```
{
"UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:111111111111:topic-name:6ea68f67-306c-4385-858b-laskdjfsd123",
"SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-1ff5318643ec183fbaddaa2a969abadf.pem",
"Signature" : "Ikjay6NCGmwhyNothdvNVWNps1OMOcBuCGT+trYqVzdSLX79cCBgZeX5ZynTlC+ewsRYFH2bVW521pK88j+Z3/uDxGBrMkd6SZ/GBF1Rnl5pB4UG4aZXLP3uxE0MDX+lUPX2aCu6ta/ii3gI7vxtqKoUzqTt8aNHVMT5GG9xjLg2yIxW97MKRLbSHug5NXetlSwYdNuwq/P85Eur6BkufpLg5aummfAwfpR9ZaNdFEqjBl0nYj96q46w6UKFHaZDEgeit1TMBYjCKM3VzuyMSOPQ==",
"SignatureVersion" : "1",
"Timestamp" : "2022-03-03T14:44:49.000Z",
"Message" : "{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Alex\"}",
"TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:111111111111:topic-name",
"MessageId" : "c765b712-d774-558a-a070-ed8801d5e34r",
"Type" : "Notification"
}
```

Please let me know what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled "Raw message delivery" in SNS subscription.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-payload-raw-message.html

> In addition to sending large payloads, with Amazon SNS you can now
> enable raw message delivery for messages delivered to either Amazon
> SQS endpoints or HTTP/S endpoints. This eliminates the need for the
> endpoints to process JSON formatting, which is created for the Amazon
> SNS metadata when raw message delivery is not selected. For example
> when enabling raw message delivery for an Amazon SQS endpoint, the
> Amazon SNS metadata is not included and the published message is
> delivered to the subscribed Amazon SQS endpoint as is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

After debugging for many many hours i realised this was the problem - Enabling raw message delivery using the AWS Management Console